# Stick cut into 3 pieces - probability they form a triangle, why is my solution wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to find an analytical solution for the classic probability problem "a stick of length 1 is cut into 3 pieces randomly, what's the probability we can form a triangle with the 3 pieces?". I'm aware there are other questions re this problem on stackexchange (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r), and I understand all the solutions given.
However, when I first tried to solve this problem I followed another approach and I got a wrong answer, and I don't understand where I am going wrong. Can someone help me?

My reasoning is as follows:

Imagine we first cut the stick in two pieces and call 
Call $X$ the r.v. defining the length of the first piece. Then suppose to cut the other piece in two and call $Y$ the length of the second piece. The remaining one has length 1-x-y.
Let $A$ be the event such that $0<x<1/2$, $0<y<1/2$ and $x+y>1/2$. Then, 
$P(A)=\int \int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$ is the probability we're looking for.

We need to find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. We know

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(Y=y|X=x)f_X(x)$

and

$f(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ Because once X is chosen, Y can range from 0 to 1-x only.

and since $X$ is uniform from 0 to 1 (we can choose the first piece anyway we want)

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(Y=y|X=x)f_X(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ over $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1-x$

However, integrating this pdf on $A$ we have

$\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{1/2-x}^{1/2} \frac{1}{1-x} dydx \neq \frac{1}{4}$, which should be the solution.

So my solution is clearly wrong. But where? Probably multiple times... and probably in the way I build the joint distribution. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, if you cut the stick into *two* pieces, $0<x<1/2$ and $0<y<1/2$ is impossible, and $x+y>1/2$ is always true.

Comment: In this model distribution of $Y$ is not uniform, since $$ \int f_{X,Y} (x,y) dx =\int_0^{1-y} (1-x)^{-1} dx =- \ln(y)$$ the way of cutting is cut at X first, then take the part until X and cut it uniformly.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. @DavidPeterson my question was not clear, apologies. I edited it: the stick is cut into three pieces, x is length of the first cut, y of the second, while the remaining has length 1-x-y. Does my model reflect this hypothesis?

Comment: @Mick do you mind expanding on that? I had in mind exactly to cut at X first, and then cut the part until X uniformily (getting the piece y and 1-x-y). Note also my answer to David above. If we get the cut X first, then Y is uniform on (0,1-x), so I made a mistake in the conditional pdf of Y or where? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong. You model gives the result you stated. Nothing wrong with that. But usually the common model is the following: choose a uniform X and a uniform Y, independently. This means that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$. Fix one end of the stick, cut at X and at Y.

Comment: @Mick, I see your point, thanks. That is indeed a different way of thinking at the problem. However, I still don't see why the result I get is not the same. Isn't mine just a different model to represent the same experiment?

Since my solution is not 1/4, probably mine is not the correct way to model the stick cutting experiment. But why is that?

Comment: Have you heard of the Bertrand paradox? Three different models give three different answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: That's very interesting, I understand that without further information on how the stick is broken both solutions are valid then. Thanks a lot @Mick! 
it's good to know that my solution is not wrong :)